# Stumped on Drag and Drop in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm stumped on trying to get drag and drop to work, so maybe someone can see where I've gone wrong. This kind of works in that it allows me to drag and recognizes where I can and cannot drop, but it never calls the doDrop function. Also, I'm not seeing where I pick up the target.

My real app has containers and items, containers can accept other containers or items - Basically a files and folders type scenario.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var stuff = ["ABC", "DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO"]
    @State var isTarget = true
    
    var body: some View
    {
        List
        {
            ForEach(stuff,id: \.self)
            { x in
                Text(x)
                    .onDrag
                        { NSItemProvider(object: x as NSString) }
            }.onDrop(of: ["public.text"], delegate: doDrop())
        }
    }
    
    struct doDrop: DropDelegate
    {
        func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool
        {
            guard info.hasItemsConforming(to: ["public.text"]) else
            {
                return false
            }
            if let item = info.itemProviders(for: ["public.text"]).first
            {
                item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.text", options: nil)
                {
                    (data, error) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        if let data = data as? String
                        {
                            print(data)
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but that one-bracket-each-line style is kind of hard to read imo

Comment: @aheze You ain't wrong, code looking like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass the initializer for a new object DoDrop.

Pass an already-initialized object whose lifetime is not limited to just that onDrop closure (e.g., your view model or self for the ContentView struct itself).

Comment: That isn't it since I've found working examples that show the function being called either way. What I did find was that someone indicated that onDrop doesn't work in a List, one needs to use onInsert, but I haven't been able to make that work either. I can successfully drag from the list to a view outside the list, but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: That's odd. I have an app published in the App Store that drags and drops into Lists.

Answer (score -1):

This should fix the reported problem, although I have not got it to pick up the dropped text yet.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View, DropDelegate
{
    @State var stuff = ["ABC", "DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO"]
    @State var isTarget = true

    var body: some View
    {
        List
         {
            ForEach(stuff,id: \.self)
            { x in
                Text(x)
                    .onDrag
                        { NSItemProvider(object: x as NSString) }
            }.onDrop(of: ["public.text"], delegate: self)
        }
    }

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool
    {
        guard info.hasItemsConforming(to: ["public.text"]) else
        {
            return false
        }
        if let item = info.itemProviders(for: ["public.text"]).first
        {
            item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.text", options: nil)
            {
                (data, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    if let data = data as? String
                    {
                        print(data)
                    }
               }
            }
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

BTW I like to have brackets on their own lines.

Comment: That didn't work for me. It starts the drag but doesn't trigger the performDrop.

Comment: I had the same problem change public.text to public.utf8-plain-text.

Comment: That didn't change anything but what I discovered is that you can't seem to drag and drop to the same list. If there is a second list you can drag from the first to the second and that works.